# Is it possible to kick players from a chat channel in Starcraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

When you create a battle.net chat channel. People can join and continuously join without approval. Is there a way to kick a unruly player from a chat channel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: No.

It is currently not possible and i haven't heard of any plans from Blizzard to change that.

Comment: Is there any possible way to mute them? I heard someone say if the creator blocks a person from the chat, they can no longer speak to anyone.

Comment: Chat channels are not bound to any specific person so unless everyone ignores the user there is no way to mute him.